# encode and decode urlstring parameters exacttarget

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Its not nice to pass the parameters in the LP and which is visible in URL ...i.e. &id=123 or sth

Is it possible to encode it and then  decode it in LP to capture the parameters (RequestParameter) in the landing page?? AMPSCRIPT??

-thx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.  I've done this very thing.  Let's say the link you send today looks like:

http://pages.exacttarget.com/page.aspx?QS=773ed3059447707d9cf0f7f1ffa7a5cc&emailAddress=test@test.com&id=123

In the email, you would build it something like:

```
%%[
      SET @queryStringPart2 = EncryptSymmetric("USE_ENCRYPTION_OF_CHOICE",  &emailAddress=test@test.com&id=123", "etcetera")
      SET @newLink = Concat("http://pages.exacttarget.com/page.aspx?QS=773ed3059447707d9cf0f7f1ffa7a5cc", "&encrypted=", @queryStringPart2)
]%%
```

Then to decode on landing page:

```
%%[
    SET @qsPart2 = QueryParameter("encrypted") /* gets the encrypted string */)
    SET @DecryptedString = DecryptSymmetric("DECRYPTION_OF_CHOICE", @qsPart2)
/* Use Substring or regex to parse the decrypted string */

]%%
```

Hope this helps!